# iPhone app freezing when network switches from 3G to 2G

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking

I can't find any information on this but really need to know for sure if it doesn't happen, or if the documentation that proves it does happen is just too hard to find!

The background story:

When my app is running on an iPhone that has a weak 3G signal, and therefore switches backwards and forwards from a weak 3G to a strong 2G and vice-versa, it seems to freeze (the app, a complete freeze for 5-10 seconds). I have had reports of this from far and wide but it's something I can't replicate as my 3G signal is too strong in my area!

If I squeeze my iPhone 4 tightly, then I can dim the signal enough that I get an alert telling me that there is no cellular data network ... before it switches to 2G briefly. This DOES cause a freeze, and I tracked it down to the alert causing the app delegate method "applicationDidBecomeActive" to be called after the alert is dismissed, but no "applicationWillResignActive" as I had expected when thinking of the normal suspend/resume process.

I changed some of the logic in my code to deal with this, and that problem is now resolved.

The question:

Are any app delegate methods called when the phone switches from 3G to 2G and vice-versa? Does the app momentarily lose it's active state and then regain it like it does in the above situation? The problem above seems to replicate exactly what my users are experience EXCEPT from the fact that I get the "no cellular data network" alert which obviously changes things a bit. They don't get this alert, but they still get the freeze.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of networking are you using in your app?

Comment: Did you got the reason and the alternative to solve this bug ?Even I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to track this using Reachability.

You can find it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I think reachability only differentiates between Wifi and cellular data, not each type of cellular data. I don't think there are any notifications sent.